# Find the trigonometric limit

Tags: limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^4} $$

Here is my solution:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^4} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x(\frac{1}{\cos x}-1)}{x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^4}*(\frac{1}{\cos x}-1)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^4}*(0)$$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^4}$$

$$ \to \lim_{x \to 0+0}\frac{\sin(0+0)}{(0+0)^4}=\frac{0}{0} \space AND \space \lim_{x \to 0-0}\frac{\sin(0-0)}{(0-0)^4}=\lim_{x \to 0-0}\frac{-\sin(0)}{(0)^4}=-\frac{0}{0}, Hence \space the \space limit \space DNE $$

*So, is that an appropriate way? I have troubles with the limits that have no solution (do not exist). I can easily find the limit with L'Hôpital's Rule, but then it turns out that the limit one-sided and do not exist. Is there any universal method for that type of limits?*

Comment: indeterminate does not mean dne!

Comment: @Joe, if $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=x^2$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/g(x)$ has a two-sided limit.

Comment: The limit with denominator $x^3$ exists.  The limit with denominator $x^2$ exists.

Comment: @chhro: Thanks for correcting my error. I'll delete my comment. I think the correct statement is that if $f(x) \to 0$ and $g(x) \to 0$, and $f$ is odd, and $g$ is even, then unless $f(x)/g(x) \to 0$ as $x\to0$, the two-sided limit does not exist.

Comment: @chhro, in my problem set the answer is "DNE". You're correct, it has one-sided limits (- and + inf).

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with the second equality, all that was left was to multiply numerator and denominator by a "conjugate"

$$\frac{\sin x(\sec x - 1)}{x^4}\cdot\frac{\sec x+1}{\sec x + 1} = \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot \frac{\tan^2x}{x^2} \cdot\frac{1}{x} \cdot\frac{1}{\sec x + 1}$$

The limit to $0$ of $xf(x)$ is

$$ 1\cdot 1^2 \cdot \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Thus the limit of $f$ to $0$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\approx0$, we know that $\sin x\approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ and $\tan x \approx x+\frac{x^3}{3}$.* Hence,
\begin{align}
\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^4} &\approx \frac{x+\frac{x^3}{3}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^4} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^4} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{2x} \, .
\end{align}
We thus conclude that the limit from the right is $\infty$, and the limit from the left is $-\infty$.

---

*(The higher-order terms of the Taylor series of $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ can safely be ignored because they contain powers of $x$ which are larger than $4$.)